# How to find even distributed values between lower and upper boundary in C#

Tags: c#

Let's say I have two values (lower boundary = 0.5, upper boundary = 100.0). Then I want to split this range 40 times so that the first is 0.5 and the 40th is 100.0. How can I find the 38 values between 0.5 and 100.0 so that the distance between the values is always the same?

Comment: You should determine the algorithm first, _then_ try to make it in c#.

Comment: All that has been posted is a program description, but that doesn't tell us what _problem_ you're having. What have you tried, and what troubles did you encounter? Please [edit] your post to include a [valid question](/help/how-to-ask) that we can answer. Reminder: make sure you know what is [on-topic](/help/on-topic); asking us to write the program for you, opinions, and external links are off-topic.

Comment: Say the range was 0..10 and you wanted a 3-way split, what do you suppose the step value would be, and how could you then generalize that?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds like a homework? You should be really able to solve this simple problem.

Always split your task into steps. Before you think of any code, you must understand the problem. Then find a solution. You can phrase the solution in words and pseudo code. Finally, you can try to implement this solution:

1. First you must find the appropriate algorithm:
   Identify the input and the output (result):
   a) calculate the *range* of your *lower_bound=0.5* (input) and *upper_bound=100* (input): *range=upper_bound-lower_bound*
   b) Then divide *range* by *steps=40* (input) to get the *interval*.
   c) Finally, walk from *lower_bound* to *upper_bound* by incrementing each step by *interval* to get each value that belongs to the *range*.
2. Implement the algorithm

```cs
void Main()
{
    double steps = 40;
    double lowerBound = 0.5;
    double upperBound = 100;
    double range = Math.Abs(upperBound - lowerBound);
    double interval = range / steps;
    var rangeValues = new List<double>();
    for (double step = lowerBound; step <= upperBound; step += interval)
    {
      rangeValues.Add(step);
    }
}
```

3. Test and improve the algorithm to improve performance and readability.  For example rename variables and move code into methods. by moving code into methods that accept the input as parameters, you can convert the hard-coded algorithm into a dynamic one.
4. Make the algorithm robust (important).
   For example, you must ensure that the variable `steps` is never *zero* to avoid an `DivideByZeroException` exception. For this reason you must validate the input before you can run the algorithm.